# Do the Daleks remember the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode [Asylum of the Daleks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asylum_of_the_Daleks)  :

> Clara uses her bond with the Daleks to delete the Doctor from the Daleks' collective telepathically-shared knowledge.

However in [The Time of the Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_of_the_Doctor) :

> The Daleks who attack the town seem to clearly remember who the Doctor is.

I can't manage to remember how is that possible. Is there any explication in the show that I missed?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This was directly addressed in the episode, when the Daleks interrupted the Doctor's parley with Tasha Lem:

> DALEK: Step away from the Dalek unit, Doctor.
>
> DOCTOR: You shouldn't even know who I am.
>
> DALEK: Information concerning the Doctor was harvested from the cadaver of Tasha Lem.

So when the Daleks converted Tasha into a Dalek puppet, they recorded her knowledge of the Doctor. Before that point in the episode, they were just attacking him as they would anyone else, and never acknowledged who he was.

Comment: Right ! I completly forgot about the Church of the Papal Mainfraime. I was wondering If I missed an episode where the Dalekd would have gotten their memory back but it was way more simple. Thanks !

Answer (score 13):

In *Asylum of the Daleks*, Clara did wipe all memory of the Doctor from the Daleks.

But in *The Time of the Doctor*, he shows up on a Dalek ship holding the eye-stalk of a destroyed Dalek.

When they saw that, they attacked him as a normal adversary. Watch the episode, and you'll see that they just screech their usual *EXTERMINATE* without mentioning The Doctor.

So, the Daleks' didn't remember that he's their eternal enemy The Doctor. He showed up with a eye-stalk and said

> *'I bring proof of courage and comradeship. What is this ship and why are you here? Identify yourselves by species and planet of origin.'*

So they attacked him like they would anyone else.

**EDIT:**

Also as @Amy mentions:

> When the Daleks eventually attacked the Church of the Papal Mainframe, they harvested data about The Doctor from Tasha Lem's Cadaver. But this was after the scene when he walks in with a Dalek eye-stalk, at which point they had not known who he was.